# HTML5 JavaScript image output

Tags: html

[Using Google Translator]
Hello, I am writing for the first time.

I followed the examples in the book in order.

This book progresses from <1.html> to <22.html> in small increments.

The image should be output from the execution result of <10.html>.

---

[problem]

<9.html>, even though the word "Enter to Start" was printed normally.

However, <10.html> suddenly does not pop up anything. There seems to be a problem with the image call.

Is there a problem with function setImage ()?

---

[Additional]

1. The images are in the same folder.
2. The image and code have the same name.
3. There was a problem with some functions added in <10.html>.
4. Debugging on a site called "html5 validator nu" has no errors.
   (← I excluded points(.) to avoid links)

   - Added functions in <10.html>:

   function drawAll ()

   function stopGame ()

   function drawPlayer ()

   function drawBk ()

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title> 레이싱 게임 </title>

    <style>
        body
        {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        canvas
        {
            background-color: #0099FF;
        }
    </style>

</head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"> </canvas>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        // 캔버스 객체
        var canvas;
        var ctx;
        var canvasBuffer;
        var bufferCtx;
        var threadSpeed = 16;

        // 캐릭터 (일단 잠수함으로 지정)
        var submarine;
        var sx, sy, sw = 60, sh = 35;

        // 배경이미지
        var background;

        //장애물
        var enemy = new Array();
        var enemyColor = ["red", "blue", "white"];
        var ellapse = 10;

        // 타이머 인스턴스
        var loopInstance;

        // 게임의 상태
        var STATE_START = false;
        var STATE_GAMEOVER = false;

        // 키 상태
        var keyPressed = [];

        // 경과 시간
        var oldTime;
        var startTime;
        var totalTime;

        window.addEventListener("load", initialize, false);
        window.addEventListener("keydown", getKeyDown, false);
        window.addEventListener("keyup", getKeyUp, false);

        function initialize()
        {
            canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            if(canvas == null || canvas.getContext==null) return;
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            canvasBuffer = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvasBuffer.width = canvas.width;
            canvasBuffer.height = canvas.height;
            bufferCtx = canvasBuffer.getContext("2d");




            // 게임 시작 메시지
            startMessage();

            // 이미지 설정
            setImage();

            // 반복 동작 설정
            loopInstance = setInterval (update, threadSpeed);
        }

        // 주기적으로 반복되는 루틴
        function update()
        {
            if((keyPressed[13] == true) && !STATE_START)    // enter
            {
                startGame();
            }

            drawAll();
        }

        function drawAll();
        {
            if(!STATE_START)
            {
                return;
            }

            else if (STATE_GAMEOVER)
            {
                stopGame();
                drawText(ctx, "Game Over", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 - 60, "bold 30px arial", "#ffff00", "center", "top");

                drawText(ctx, "Spacebar to Restart", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 - 20, "bold 25px arial", "#ffffff", "center", "top");
            }

            else
            {
                // 배경 이미지 출력
                drawBk();

                // 잠수함 출력
                drawPlayer();
                ctx.drawImage(canvasBuffer, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        function stopGame()
        {
            STATE_START = false;
        }

        // 잠수함 유닛 출력
        function drawPlayer()
        {
            bufferCtx.drawImage(submarine, sx-sw/2, sy-sh/2);
        }

        // 게임 배경 이미지 출력
        function drawBk()
        {
            bufferCtx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
        }

        function startGame()
        {
            // 게임 시작 상태
            STATE_START = true;

            // 캐릭터의 초기 위치
            sx = canvas.width/2 - 18;
            sy = canvas.height/2 - 18;
            sw = 60;
            sh = 35;
        }

        function getKeyDown (event)
        {
            keyPressed[event.keyCode] = true;
        }

        function getKeyUp(event)
        {
            keyPressed[event.keyCode] = false;
        }

        function setImage()
        {
            submarine = new Image();
            submarine.src = "C.jpg";     // 보류

            background = new Image();
            background.src = "back.jpg"; // 보류
        }

        function startMessage()
        {
            drawText(ctx, "Enter to Start", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 - 60, "bold 30px arial", "#ffff00", "center", "top");
            drawText(ctx, "조작:방향키 ←↑→↓", canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 - 20, "bold 20px arial", "#ffffff", "center", "top");
        }

        function drawText(ctx, text, x, y, font, color, align, base)
        {
            if(font != undefined) ctx.font = font;
            if(color != undefined) ctx.fillStyle = color;
            if(align != undefined) ctx.textAlign = align;
            if(base != undefined) ctx.textBaseline = base;
            ctx.fillText(text, x, y);
        }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1SbH.jpg):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: remove Error console Screenshot]

console function drawAll() error